# Problem rendering a video (Cycles / Node Editor / VSE)

Tags: rendering, video

I am trying to import a video to use as a background. I used cycles render but the video doesn't show up. I uploaded the video using video editor, then added the scene then added alpha over to the images. I used node editor to do the same thing and the video isn't showing up. I tried to find videos online but everyone is using blender render, the problem is the texture of the object I have only shows up in cycles and not blender render and I want to be able to see everything. Is there a way I can view the video?

the video is a .mov file but it is very big about 500MB.!

[here is the rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mrZT.png)

[image: here is the second part of the compositor, I couldn't fit it all in one screenshot]

[image]

here is my VSE editor
[image]

that was all I did.

Comment: the video was quite large, is that a problem?

Comment: Nope, if you have enought RAM... It rather seems to me that you haven't turned on the "transparent" setting in 'Render' panel > 'Film' section.

Comment: it worked, I tried transparent before and it didn't work. I probably didn't wait for it to fully render.

Comment: OK, so you can answer your own question :) !

Comment: Perhaps try connecting the 'Alpha' output of the render node to the 'Fac' node of the AlphaOver node?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to check the "Transparent" check box, under the subsection "Film" of the tab "Render" (the icon is a camera), on the "Properties" panel.

[image]

Then you need to connect the "Alpha" output from the RenderLayer to the "Fac" (Factor).

[image]

And, finally, where I have blue, you would connect your video.

[image]